# 403 Forbidden returned by trying to download a video in Java code

Tags: java, http, nginx, http-headers, http-status-code-403

I want to download an embedded video from a website

The video is easily accessed in a browser but I'm struggling with getting it in Java

Below is the network tab with the website open after clicking a play button

[image]

If I copy the Request URL add a new tab, paste and hit enter the segment is downloaded

[image]

However, if I open a new Incognito window and try that I get 403 Forbidden (I also tried to open the video in Incognito mode, pressed the play button, then copied the url and hit enter, the video downloaded successfully, but I get 403 in Normal mode instead)

[image]

I get the same result while running the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        String baseUrl = "someUrl/ih4mxuprbnvyb3iihebxt26uxqo5x32qhldeyaejlhbmm7kga7llvftoqdia/seg-1-v1-a1.ts";
        URL url = new URL(baseUrl);

        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        con.setRequestMethod("GET");

        con.setRequestProperty("sec-ch-ua", "\"Google Chrome\";v=\"87\", \" Not;A Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Chromium\";v=\"87\"");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");
        con.setRequestProperty("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
        con.setRequestProperty("sec-ch-ua-mobile", "?0");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_0_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36");

        System.out.println(con.getResponseCode());

    }
```

I've tried adding the same headers but it didn't work. What am I missing? Thanks in advance

Comment: check `referrer policy`

Comment: Also, did the site require a login at some point?

Comment: @JimGarrison No, it doesn't. Otherwise, it would've been too obvious

Comment: @EmptyBrain it's `strict-origin-when-cross-origin` in both 200 and 403 as well